# Visual Studio Code and imports. Path Problem?

Tags: visual-studio-code, import, path

I'm having a problem with VSCode and syntax coloring.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaA4z.jpg)
I have these imports but VSCode won't turn them green even though code itself is working fine.

When I drag my main code and modules to workspace VSCode founds the imports and turns them green.
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqzMr.jpg)

How am I able to make my imports turn green without my modules being on workspace?
I want to start my code straight from my desktop.
There must be somekind of path problem but I don't know how to solve this.

I uninstalled and reinstalled Python and VSCode.
I deleted AppData/Roaming/Code files and .vscode extensions files.
These didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Fixed with Pylance 2023.4.11 pre-release version.** [Github issue closed](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4142#issuecomment-1498266826)

Many people experience the same issue (including myself);

- https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4142
- https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4149

Workarounds would be;

- adding your site-packages folder to Pylance's "extra paths" option in preferences. [Image: Pylance Extra Paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS2G4.png)
- roll back to an older release of Pylance, 2023.3.20 should work [Image: Previous Pylance releases in VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPBVc.png)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! :) It's a relief to know that I'm not the only one with this problem. Thanks for the great advices too, I'll try these to fix the problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post that I got this problem fixed (if someone is struggling with the same issue..)

I downloaded previous Pylance version >>> v2023.3.21

Now my all modules are working just like they should (also when I run my code straight from the desktop).